# How to yield items from multiple h5 files simultaneously

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield, h5py

I have a list of h5 files
my single generator is like this

```
class H5Dataset_all(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, h5_path):
        # super(dataset_h5, self).__init__()
        self.h5_path = h5_path
        self._h5_gen = None
 
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if self._h5_gen is None:
            self._h5_gen = self._get_generator()
            next(self._h5_gen)
        return self._h5_gen.send(index)

    def _get_generator(self):
        with h5py.File(self.h5_path, 'r') as record:
            index = yield
            while True:
                aligned_t = record['aligned_t'][index]
                fusion_t = record['fusion_t'][index]
                sensor_t = record['sensor_t'][index]
                sensor_t_1 = record['sensor_t_1'][index]
                # delta = record['delta'][index]
                pad_num = record['pad_num'][index]
                radar_t = record['radar_t'][index]
                radar_t_1 = record['radar_t_1'][index]
                index = yield aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t, sensor_t_1, pad_num, radar_t, radar_t_1
```

How can I open all of my h5 files simultaneously as one generator like this:

```
  def __getitem__(self, index):
        features = [self.getitem_single(index,x) for x in range(len(self.h5_path))]
        aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t, sensor_t_1, pad_num, radar_t, radar_t_1 = zip(*features)
   
        pad_num = np.array(pad_num)
        aligned_t = np.array(aligned_t)
        fusion_t = np.array(fusion_t)
        sensor_t_11 = np.array(sensor_t_1)
        sensor_t_1 = sensor_t_11[...,:-1]
        sensor_ids = np.array(sensor_t)[...,-1]
        sensor_t = np.array(sensor_t)[...,:-1]
        radar_t_1 = np.array(radar_t_1)[...,:-1]
        radar_t = np.array(radar_t)[...,:-1]
        
         return aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t, sensor_t_1, pad_num, radar_t, radar_t_1, sensor_ids
    def getitem_single(self, index, path_id):
        if self._h5_gen[path_id] is None:
            self._h5_gen[path_id] = self._get_generator(path_id)
            next(self._h5_gen[path_id])
        return self._h5_gen[path_id].send(index)
    def _get_generator(self,path_id):
        with h5py.File(self.h5_path[path_id], 'r') as record:
            index = yield
            while True:
                aligned_t = record['aligned_t'][index]
                fusion_t = record['fusion_t'][index]
                sensor_t = record['sensor_t'][index]
                sensor_t_1 = record['sensor_t_1'][index]
                # delta = record['delta'][index]
                pad_num = record['pad_num'][index]
                radar_t = record['radar_t'][index]
                radar_t_1 = record['radar_t_1'][index]
                index = yield aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t, sensor_t_1, pad_num, radar_t, radar_t_1
```

This code gives me a deadlock which I can never get the return clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to read the same indexed value from several datasets in several H5 files in 1 call. If so, this should solve your problem.

Note: Before I wrote the Class generator for multiple files, I rewrote (and simplified) the one you posted for a single file. My rewrite works on 2 assumptions: 1) all datasets in all files have the same shape, and 2) you are simply looping on the dataset.shape index. (This is a reasonable assumption b/c it's also necessary for your generator to work. If the datasets have different sizes you will get an index error.)

Here is the revised class for a single file:

```
class H5Dataset_all():
    def __init__(self, h5_path):
        self.h5_path = h5_path

    def h5_generator(self):
        record = h5py.File(self.h5_path, 'r')
        nrows = record['aligned_t'].shape[0]
        for index in range(nrows):
            print(f'index in h5_generator(): {index}')
            aligned_t = record['aligned_t'][index]
            fusion_t = record['fusion_t'][index]
            sensor_t = record['sensor_t'][index]
            yield aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t
        record.close()
```

That produces the same results as your class when I tested with a simple file I created. Assuming that's acceptable, it's I just modified the class to use a list of files. It opens each file and saves the h5py File object to a list. Then it's a simple matter to loop over the list of files and datasets. See code below.

```
class H5Dataset_all():
    def __init__(self, h5_paths):
        self.h5_paths = h5_paths

    def h5_generator(self):
        h5f_list = []
        h5_data = []
        for h5_fname in self.h5_paths:
            h5f = h5py.File(h5_fname, 'r')
            h5f_list.append(h5f)
        
        nrows = h5f_list[0]['aligned_t'].shape[0]
        for index in range(nrows):
            print(f'\nindex in h5_generator: {index}')
            for record in h5f_list:
                aligned_t = record['aligned_t'][index]
                fusion_t = record['fusion_t'][index]
                sensor_t = record['sensor_t'][index]
                h5_data.append( (aligned_t, fusion_t, sensor_t) )
            yield h5_data 
        
        for h5f in h5f_list:
            h5f.close()
```

Here is the code I wrote that creates 3 files to test the classes above:

```
f_names = ['file1.h5', 'file2.h5', 'file3.h5']
ds_names = ['aligned_t', 'fusion_t', 'sensor_t'] 
cnt = 1
for f_name in f_names:
    with h5py.File(f_name,'w') as h5f:
        for ds_name in ds_names:
            h5f.create_dataset(ds_name, data=np.arange(cnt,cnt+10))
            cnt += 10
```